# SparkR on Dataproc (Spark 1.5.x) does not work

Tags: sparkr, google-cloud-dataproc

When I attempt to use SparkR on a Cloud Dataproc cluster (version 0.2) I get an error like the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:
/usr/lib/spark/R/lib/sparkr.zip (Permission denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at
org.apache.spark.deploy.RPackageUtils$.zipRLibraries(RPackageUtils.scala:215)
at
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:371)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:153)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

How can I fix this so I can use SparkR?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue is due to a bug in the Spark 1.5 series ([JIRA here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11304)). To fix this, run the following command on the master node either by SSHing into the master node or by using an [initialization action](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/init-actions).

`sudo chmod 777 /usr/lib/spark/R/lib`

This issue is supposed to be fixed in Spark 1.6 which Cloud Dataproc will eventually support in a new image version in the future.